# What does ipfs init do?

Tags: git, ethereum, ipfs

I'm new to ipfs, and I want to understand what I am doing. I understand git quite a bit, is there a parallel in understanding? My questions:-

- What exactly does `ipfs init` do?
- What is a global object repository?
- I do not run a daemon yet because `ipfs daemon` does that, but do I make any of my local files public by running init?
- Is `ipfs init` a parallel to `git init`?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

From [`ipfs/js-ipfs` PR 91](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/pull/91), the main steps behind an `ipfs init` are:

> - check for repo existence
> - generate new peer id
> - generate + write config
> - write version
> - add default assets to the repo
> - pin default assets to the repo
> - set + publish IPNS record

I don't have much data on a "global object repository", except that the [goal of IPFS](https://github.com/ipfs/ipfs) is to be global (see [its name origin](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/why-the-name-ipfs/307)):

> IPFS (the InterPlanetary File System) is a new hypermedia distribution protocol, addressed by content and identities.

As [mentioned in this thread](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/significance-of-key-generated-by-ipfs-init/279/2):

> `ipfs init` generated the files in `~/.ipfs/`, including `config`, which contains your private key.
>   You'll notice that in config your peer identity is listed above that private key.

You still need to [`ipfs add` your files](https://ipfs.io/docs/commands/#ipfs-add) and to [publish them (`ipfs name`)](https://ipfs.io/docs/commands/#ipfs-name)